# C++ operators overloading when having constructor conversion

Tags: c++, performance, operator-overloading

So I'm not too sure if the title well describes the problem. Essentially I'm wondering if I have a class `A`, which has a constructor from `const &` from type `B` and `C`, if I have the operator `*=` for instance, it will work form both `A *= A`, `A *= B` and `A *= C`. Now if using SFINAE I can write this separately for each of the three cases, where the individual `A *= B` and `A *= C` might be just a very small margin faster, should I even bother implementing or just implementing for `A *= A` is enough?

Comment: Don't describe your code in prose - show the actual code. It's worth a thousand words.

Comment: SFINAE is used with template functions. Nowhere in your description do you mention templates. Do you have some? How does SFINAE get into the picture? Why can't you simply write three overloads of `operator*=`, taking `A`, `B` and `C` correspondingly?

Answer (score 4):

> might be just a very small margin faster, should I even bother implementing

Here's the decision process:

1. Does my code work?

> Yes.

2. Are my users complaining about the slow operation of my program or library? They haven't got a virus scanner hogging all the available CPU and thrashing the disk for example?

> Yes, they're really justifiably complaining.

3. Have I profiled the code and narrowed the problem down to this one overload operator?

> Yes

4. Really? I don't believe you - please check again.

> No, it really was that.

5. Alright then, I guess you'd better implement that extra operator. Congratulations, now you have another code path to debug and maintain for the rest of this software's life.

"Early optimisation is the root of all kinds of evil", as the saying goes. It just makes work for your colleagues and causes you to focus your time in all the wrong places.

Comment: *"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"* ~ [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth#Computer_Programming_as_an_Art_.281974.29)